# How to automate password entry for subprocess command in python?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Executing above command will prompt for password entry as below,

```
Password for 'username':
```

This prompt will interrupt automation process.
How to automate this password entry ?
or any other better ways to handle it ?
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
password = b"123"
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=password)
```